# How to retrieve specific activity instance from backstack?

Tags: android, history

I have 2 activities, Activity_A (set as Single task) and Activity_B (set as default).

Activity_A task Affinity is different from Activity_B: it has multiple instances like Activity_B(1) and Activity_B(2) ) now. If I make an intent from A (with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) to B, B(1) is on top of the stack, then goes back to A, leaving B(1) on stack. Then I make another intent to Activity_B, therefore, the stack would be like this:

b(2) <-- b(2) is now on top of stack.
b(1)

then I have to go back again to Activity_A, leaving (b1) and b(2) on stack.

My question is: How do i get back to b(1)? I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT and/or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, but I always gone back to (b2). Is there any possible way to get stack index array or something, that I can use to trace my activities in stack?